# Forecasting Monthly Timeseries Data in Excel

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, excel

I am trying to create a forecast using a monthly timeseries data set of marketing expenses for a fictional company. The data looks something like this:

[image: Marketing Expenses Data Set]

Using linear regression to forecast future sales, I get the following result:

[image: Linear Regression]

My problem lies with the seasonality of the marketing expenses (higher in the summer months for instance). I would ideally like to calculate to forecasted values of future months including seasonality. I read somewhere about ARIMA forecasting, but am really searching for some best ideas on how to accomplish the task.

To be clear, I do not **JUST** want a chart and trendline, but the data to support it too.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Seasonal) ARIMA would be one possibility, but fitting it with plain Excel without specific plugins would be a major pain.

An alternative would be [Exponential Smoothing](http://otexts.org/fpp2/expsmooth.html), specifically [seasonal Exponential Smoothing, also known as the Holt-Winters method](http://otexts.org/fpp2/holt-winters.html). The formulas can easily be coded in Excel.

I warmly recommend [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice*, 2nd edition, by Athanasopoulos and Hyndman](http://otexts.org/fpp2/). And I also recommend that you consider looking at R. *FPP2* is a good introduction to time series forecasting using R.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at it. I have R knowledge, but unfortunately my work only allows Excel. Trying to convince them that it's free and not dangerous...